# Как запретить нажатие кнопки на html форме фильтра joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla, php, ajax, javascript

Здравствуйте! Сайт работает под управление cms joomla 1.5 + virtuemart 1.1.6, дописал фильтр по параметрам товара, вот например http://www.kover2.mnogomesta.ru/component/virtuemart/22- , скажите как можно запрещать к нажатию кнопку "Подобрать" если в фильтре стоят "дефолтные" значения (т.е. любая длинна, любая ширина, любая форма, любая цена, все производители) ? Вроде как аяксом надо, но не хотелось бы аякстут прикручивать. Подскажите может есть какое -решение по проще? С уважением.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну нужно запоминать дефолтные значения и перед отработкой нажатия сравнивать значения из фильтра с дефолтными.

Comment: т.е. можно для события  submit() прописать функцию, которая просто вернёт false в случае совпадения с дефолтными значениями. Понял спасибо! ...я просто поначалу стал думать над тем как атрибут disabled="disabled" туда добавить и завис на этом.  =))